# Does a mobile phone app have the ability to control the output current?

Tags: current, usb, mobile

After some brief research online, I found that the USB port is capable of starting a simple fan. Meaning the USB charging port can output current into an external device.

Which leads to my question, is it possible for a mobile phone app to alter or control the output current? Has anybody seen or done any sort of experiment on it?

Answer (score 2):

I assume the question is whether a mobile phone's USB port, when in USB host mode (and therefore supplies the VBUS), has any ability to control the output.

The answer is NO, USB VBUS provides fixed 5 V output, with optional current limit either at 100/150 mA (if the device is designated as "low-power USB host"), or at 500/900 mA if manufacturer elected to sacrifice its battery life and designates the phone as "high-power host".

The USB framework doesn't define any means to control or regulate VBUS output power other than shut it off due to overcurrent (which is optional). So no mobile APP can do this job. If you want to control a fan with variable speed, you need to design some external circuitry for that.

Answer (score 0):

Anything is possible if you have the money. But mostly no. Most phones do not have a user controllable voltage or current output. Some have software controllable output but require rooting or OS level control. Most of the time it is on/off instead of variable current. Many phones do have a power management ic with the capability, but do not implement it in their OS.

Then you have other options. Like adding on a device that will let you control the voltage or current. A Bluetooth or USB interface maybe, controlling a microcontroller or variable regulator. This is more likely to work across multiple phones as you control the hardware and software requirements.